# How to write where condition, for date less than or equal to some value, in nest.js TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using nest.js and TypeORM. I need to make a query that returns all the rows from a table, where facility_id equals some value, and date is less than or equal to (<=) some date value.

I read the documentation about [nest.js](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database), and I couldn't find a proper way to do it.

Also, I read the official GitHub documentation for [typeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md).

Here is my code. It would be great if it could be done with find method from EntityRepository

```
import { DeleteResult, EntityRepository, Repository, UpdateResult } from "typeorm";
import { Reservations} from "src/Entities/reservations.entity";
import { Facility} from "src/Entities/facility.entity";
import { PaginationParams } from "src/pagination.model";
import { LessThanOrEqual } from "typeorm";



@EntityRepository(Reservation)
export class ReservationRepository extends Repository<Reservation> {

    
    
    async findByFacility(ustanovaId, paginationParams, dateParams): Promise<Reservation[]> {

        return await this.find({where: { termin: LessThanOrEqual(new Date(2021, 0, 1))},
             relations: ["users", "facility"],
             take: paginationParams.limit,
             skip: paginationParams.offset,
             order: {
                 [paginationParams.orderby]: paginationParams.order.toUpperCase()
             }});
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't given the proper information about `Reservation` and `Facility` entities, I am guessing two possible scenarios (usually both the scenarios will be true). You can select the code solution from either.

#### 1. `Reservation` entity has a `facility_id` column

```js
const facilityId = "YourFacilityID";

return this.find({
  where: {
    termin: LessThanOrEqual(new Date(2021, 0, 1)),
    facility_id: facilityId
  },
  relations: ["users", "facility"],
  take: paginationParams.limit,
  skip: paginationParams.offset,
  order: {
    [paginationParams.orderby]: paginationParams.order.toUpperCase()
  }
});
```

#### 2. `Reservation` entity has `facility` reference

`Reservation` entity has an `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne` relationship with `Facility` entity where the relationship is named `facility` and `Facility` entity has `id` which is equal to `facility_id` you explained in the question.

```js
const facilityId = "YourFacilityID";

return this.find({
  where: {
    termin: LessThanOrEqual(new Date(2021, 0, 1)),
    facility: { id: facilityId }
  },
  relations: ["users", "facility"],
  take: paginationParams.limit,
  skip: paginationParams.offset,
  order: {
    [paginationParams.orderby]: paginationParams.order.toUpperCase()
  }
});
```

Also, `return await` is actually redundant and you can always replace it with just `return`.

Hope this helps. Cheers!